# An error has occured like this "local variable 'words' referenced before assignment" already tried putting words global

Tags: python

I'm getting this error:

> An error has occured like this "local variable 'words' referenced before assignment"

How can I solve it? This is my code:

```
def bag_of_words(sentence):
    sentence_words = clean_up_sentence(sentence)
    bag = [0] * len(words) 
    for w in sentence_words:
        for i, words in enumerate(words):
            if word == w:
                bag[i] = 1
    return np.array(bag)
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
bag = [0] * len(words)
```

you are using the variable `words` but it doesn't exist in this context